# How to extract the date only from date time stamp format in netezza

Tags: sql, date, netezza

Currently I have a date which is “16jun2019 “ but I have a table which has a column named abc_TS which has values such as 18MAY2016 16:11:18:46.5555 . I want to use where condition such as abc_TS > ‘16jun2019 ‘. As the formats are different Iam not able to filter . Please help me how I can change my column to this format “16jun2019”.

Comment: Hello - Welcome to SO. What is the format of your column abc_TS ? Is it string(char or varchar) or datetime.

Comment: @VarunT it is date format

Comment: @user13365072 . . . What does "date format" mean?  Columns have *types*, not *formats*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff date type sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, you are storing your values as dates and timestamps *and not as strings*.

If the value is stored correctly, then just use:

```
abc_TS >= '2019-06-16'::timestamp
```

If not, you need to convert to a valid type:

```
to_timestamp(abc_TS, 'DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS.FFFF') >= '2019-06-16'::timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 WHERE  FORMAT (abc_TS, 'dd-MM-yy')  > ('16-06-2019')
```